# How to pass function arguments into a function inside the function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to build a tool that assigns a value based on a method function argument that I choose in the `assignment` function. The problem is that the methods I use have different function arguments, i.e. `assign_one` has `n_groups` and `assign_two` has `direction` and `distance` . Is there an elegant way to keep my `assignment` function, but be able to pass in different function arguments to the functions I call inside (i.e. `assign_one` and `assign_two`)?

Here is an example,

```
def assign_one(df, n_groups):
    ...
    
def assign_two(df, direction, distance):
    ...

def assignment(grid, method)

    if method == 'randomized':
        grid['grid_id'] = assign_one(grid, n_groups)
    if method == 'unique':
        grid['grid_id'] = assign_two(grid, direction, distance)

   
assignment(grid, method='unique', n_groups=10)

assignment(grid, method='randomized', direction='diagonal', distance=50)
```

Comment: Have you tried using a lambda `lambda: print("hi")` as your argument?

Comment: Using `*args` and `**kw`?

Comment: Try to use packing and unpacking arguments. That will work.¨[Look the Resource](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/?utm_campaign=DonanimHaber&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=DonanimHaber)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give your `assignment()` function a `**kwargs` parameter, that lets arbitrary keyword arguments be passed into it. `kwargs` will then register inside `assignment()` as an ordinary dict with key-value pairs, and you can take whichever keys you assume to have been passed, and pass them along to whichever method you need.

```
def assignment(grid, method, **kwargs)
    if method == 'randomized':
        grid['grid_id'] = assign_one(grid, kwargs.get('n_groups'))
    if method == 'unique':
        grid['grid_id'] = assign_two(grid, kwargs.get('direction'), kwargs.get('distance'))
```

I use `.get()` instead of the standard square-bracket notation because `.get()` doesn't immediately cause an error if the key isn't present (instead, it returns `None`, or you can specify a different default value to return if it isn't there). Since `kwargs` is for all intents and purposes a dict, you can decide what exactly you want to do with it yourself.

Comment: Why not passing just `**kwargs` and let the responsibility of correct arguments on the caller of `assignment`?

Comment: @JanStránský because if the user passes more kwargs than `assign_one()` can handle (e.g. providing all keywords applicable to all possible methods, but then giving only one specific value for `method`) then trying to call `assign_one(grid, **kwargs)` produces a `TypeError: got an unexpected keyword argument`, which OP might not want.

Comment: Got it, thanks, didn't consider the need of modification of the other functions also accepting `**kw`, which really may be undesired

Answer (score 1):

You can use partial application of `assign_one` and `assign_two` to create functions which have the same signature, that you can pass into `assignment`, by using [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

```
from functools import partial


def assign_one(df, n_groups):
    ...
    
def assign_two(df, direction, distance):
    ...

def assignment(grid, method):
    grid['grid_id'] = method(grid)
    
   
assignment(grid, method=partial(assign_one, n_groups=10))
assignment(grid, method=partial(assign_two, direction='diagonal', distance=50))
```

If you want to keep the `unique`, `randomized` labels, you could also create a dictionary containing the partially applied functions:

```
methods = {
    'unique': partial(assign_one, n_groups=10),
    'randomized': partial(assign_two, direction='diagonal', distance=50)
}    

def assignment(grid, method):
    grid['grid_id'] = methods[method](grid)

   
assignment(grid, method='unique')
assignment(grid, method='randomized')
```

Or you could use a hybrid where you only store the original functions, but not the partially applied arguments, in the dictionary:

```
methods = {
    'unique': assign_one,
    'randomized': assign_two
}    

def assignment(grid, method):
    grid['grid_id'] = method(grid)

   
assignment(grid, partial(methods['unique'], n_groups=10))
assignment(grid, partial(methods['randomized'], direction='diagonal', distance=50))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use default arguments:

```
def assignment(grid, method, n_groups=None, direction=None, distance=None):

   # ... Your code
   if direction is not None and distance is not None:
      # Process randomized
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def assign_one(df, n_groups):
    ...
    
def assign_two(df, direction, distance):
    ...

def assignment(grid, method, *args, **kwargs)

    if method == 'randomized':
        grid['grid_id'] = assign_one(grid, *args, **kwargs)
    if method == 'unique':
        grid['grid_id'] = assign_two(grid, *args, **kwargs)
```